# Why is there a whitespace in my program's output?

Tags: c++

> When  burning  a  DVD  it  is  essential  that  the  laser  beam  burning  pits  onto the  surface  is  constantly  fed  with  data,  otherwise  the  DVD  fails.  Most leading DVD  burn  applications  make  use  of  a  circular  buffer  to  stream  data from the hard disk onto the DVD. The first part, the ‘ writing process’ fills up a circular buffer with data, then the ‘ burning process’ begins to read from the buffer as the laser beam burns pits onto the surface of the DVD. If the buffer 
>   starts  to  become  empty,  the  application  should  continue  filling  up  the 
>   emptied  space  in  the  buffer  with  new  data  from  the  disk.  Implement  this 
>   scenario using Circular Queue.

For the above question I wrote the code as follows

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
#define max 5
struct queue
{
    char a[max];
    int f,r;
}q;
void initialize()
{
    q.f=q.r=-1;
}
int enqueue(char c)
{
    if(((q.f==0)&&(q.r==max-1)) || (q.r+1==q.f))
        return 1;
    else{
    if(q.r==-1)
    {
        q.r=0;
        q.f=0;
    }
    else if(q.r==max-1)
        q.r=0;
    else
        q.r++;
    q.a[q.r]=c;
    }return 0;
}
char dequeue()
{
    if(q.f==-1)
    {
        cout<<"Empty queue";
        return '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        char c = q.a[q.f];
        if(q.r==q.f)
            q.r=q.f=-1;
        else if(q.f==max-1)
            q.f=0;
        else
            q.f++;
        return c;
    }
}
void display()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<max-1;i++)
        cout<<q.a[i]<<"\t";
    cout<<"\nfront: "<<q.f<<"\trear: "<<q.r<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    string str,str1;
    cout<<"Enter a String to write data in DVD\n";
    getline(cin,str,'#');
    int i,f,choice;

    for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        f=enqueue(str[i]);
        if(f==1)
        {
            do{
            cout<<"Buffer is:\n";
            display();
            cout<<"Enter 1 to read and 2 to exit\n";
            cin>>choice;
            if(choice==1)
            {
                str1=str1+dequeue();
                cout<<"output: "<<str1<<endl;
            }
            f=enqueue(str[i]);
            i++;
            }while(choice!=2);
        }
        if(choice==2)
            break;
        f=0;
    }
}
```

I don't know why I am getting a whitespcae when the code runs

[image]

Can anyone point out where I am making mistake?

Comment: One thing, you have the code posted as text, so you can cut that from your image to make it easier to view.

Comment: You shouldn't `#define max`, because this may break the standard library `max` with weird error messages. Using (with C++11) `constexpr int MAX = 4;` respects namespaces and is better C++-style.

Comment: Sorry I am new here . I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `initialize`, so `q.f` and `q.r` are not `-1`. In your case, they are `0`, so the system thinks that there is already something in `a[0]` and prints this. It's not printable, so you only see the `\t` after it. For this reason, initialization should be done in a constructor which you can't forget to call.

Starting with C++11, you can initialize the `f` and `r` directly with

```
struct queue
{
    char a[max];
    int f=-1, r=-1;
} q;
```

Comment: thank you very much . This was indeed a stupid mistake I did. :)